# crypto.decipher causes stream not to close in node js

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to decrypt a file and send it in a response to a client. It works fine for just downloading the file, like this:

```
input.pipe(res);
```

but when I add the decipher into the pipe, like this:

```
input.pipe(decipher).pipe(res);
```

It causes the file download to stay open in the browser. Do I need to close the decipher stream or something?
Here's the full method:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var filePath = 'C:\\Users\\Anthony\\test';
    var stat = fs.statSync(filePath);

    var key = '1234asdf';
    var decipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes-256-cbc', key)

    res.setHeader('Content-Length', stat.size);
    res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=test.mp4');
    var input = fs.createReadStream(filePath);

    input.pipe(decipher).pipe(res);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely what is happening is that you're giving the browser the encoded file length and not the decrypted file length, which may be different. You could try omitting the `Content-Length` header entirely and see if that works (this will cause chunked encoding to be used instead).